# Indoor Mango leaves drooping and brown

Tags: diagnosis, leaves, indoors, mango

**Environment:**

I have been growing a mango plant indoors from the pit in a clay pot for roughly 2-3 months.
I live in Canada and it is currently Winter. I have a 6000K grow light which points directly at the plant. It is also sitting on a window ledge, but since it is winter, it doesn't get too much natural lighting from that. I also have a humidifier running on the room most of the time. My watering schedule is typically once I stick my finger in the pot and feel it dry (usually occurs a few times per week?). The water I use has been a mix of softened tap water + reverse osmosis water (about 2/3 tap water and 1/3 RO water).

**Problem:**
Some of the leaves are completely drooped down and a brownish color. The other leaves appear to be healthy.
Here is a picture so you can visualize the issue I am describing.
[image: Drooping and brown leaves]
[image]

**Question(s)**

Is this bad? What do you think is going on and how can I fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They seems quite healthy to me. Newly grown young leaves of mango trees are purple or brown. The petiole of the young leaves are not strong enough to bear the weight of the leaves hence they are drooped down. [image]

When they mature, they will become strong, deep green and they will become like other leaves beneath them. No need to worry about it.

You will get more information from [here](https://homeguides.sfgate.com/mango-fruit-leaves-trees-35688.html) and [here](http://www.extento.hawaii.edu/kbase/crop/crops/i_mango.htm).